# Laravel 10.x. Login and register form on the same page. Validation $error issue

Tags: laravel

I try use login and register form on the same page and everything works fine except validation.

Error msg from login goes to register form and back from register to login form because they use the same $error variable.
When I change input names in register then I have problem with User::class and Rules\Password::defaults() couse I dont have this fields in db.

Maybe is a chance to set some aliases in validation ex. 'register_name' => 'name' or use different value for $errors for login and register.

Comment: You could use different messages_bags or named message_bags for your error https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#named-error-bags